# Laplace equation and separation of variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please help me to satisfied the conditions of this Laplace equation .

i started to separate the variables and i got two equations which are X''-hx=0 and Y''+hy=0  , but I did not know how should i continue .

Thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Tnx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

### Matching BC at $(x,2)$

Let $\displaystyle \phi_{1}(x,y)=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}
\sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{2} \right)
\sinh \left( \frac{n\pi y}{2} \right)$ where

$\phi_{1}(x,0)=\phi_{1}(0,y)=\phi_{1}(x,2)=0$ and $\phi_{1}(x,2)=u(x,2)$

By $\displaystyle
\int_{0}^{L}
\sin \left( \frac{m\pi t}{L} \right)
\sin \left( \frac{n\pi t}{L} \right) dt=
\frac{L}{2} \delta_{m,n}$

$\displaystyle a_{n}=\frac{1}{\sinh n\pi}
\int_{0}^{2} u(x,2) \sin \left( \frac{n\pi x}{2} \right) dx$

### Matching BC at $(2,y)$

Let $\displaystyle \phi_{2}(x,y)=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}
\sinh \left( \frac{n\pi x}{2} \right)
\sin \left( \frac{n\pi y}{2} \right)$ where

$\phi_{2}(0,y)=\phi_{2}(x,0)=\phi_{2}(2,y)=0$ and $\phi_{2}(2,y)=u(2,y)$

$\displaystyle b_{n}=\frac{1}{\sinh n\pi}
\int_{0}^{2} u(2,y) \sin \left( \frac{n\pi y}{2} \right) dy$

### Combining

$u(x,y)=\phi_{1}(x,y)+\phi_{2}(x,y)$

May also refer to **3.1-3** from [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde301.pdf)